# Refactor IUnitOfWork

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**Premisse:**

I am folowing IUnitOfWork Patterns I created a Base class with my methods to persist data.

**My Problem:**

I found a problem to write a method Next Number of table from SQLServer, because of this, I am repeating this method in every class .

**Classes:**

BaseContext Class:

```
public class BaseContext<T> : DbContext where T : class
{

    public DbSet<T> DbSet
    {
        get;
        set;
    }



    public BaseContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

        Database.SetInitializer<BaseContext<T>>(null);

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {



        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        // Class Mapping from IMapping

        var typesToMapping = (from x in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                              where x.IsClass && typeof(IMapping).IsAssignableFrom(x)
                              select x).ToList();

        foreach (var mapping in typesToMapping)
        {
            dynamic mappingClass = Activator.CreateInstance(mapping);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mappingClass);
        }


    }

    public virtual void ChangeObjectState(object model, EntityState state)
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this)
                      .ObjectContext
                      .ObjectStateManager
                      .ChangeObjectState(model, state);
    }


    // Implement IUnitOfWork




    public virtual int Save(T model)
    {
        this.DbSet.Add(model);
        this.ChangeObjectState(model, EntityState.Added);
        return this.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual int Update(T model, int id)
    {
        var entity = DbSet.Find(id);
        this.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
        return this.SaveChanges();

    }

    public virtual void Delete(T model)
    {
        var entry = this.Entry(model);
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
            this.DbSet.Attach(model);

        this.ChangeObjectState(model, EntityState.Deleted);
        this.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return this.DbSet.ToList();
    }

    public virtual T GetById(object id)
    {
        return this.DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return this.DbSet.Where(expression);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> OrderBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return this.DbSet.OrderBy(expression);
    }


}
```

My method NextNumber in every class:

```
public class VersionDao : BaseContext<Version>, IUnitOfWork<Version>
{
    public int Next() => DbSet.Max(x => x.VersionId) + 1;
}

public class TicketDao : BaseContext<ViewModelTicket> , IUnitOfWork<ViewModelTicket>
{
    public int Next() => DbSet.Max(x => x.TicketId) + 1;
}

public class CompanyDao : BaseContext<Company>, IUnitOfWork<Company>
{
    public int Next() => DbSet.Max(x => x.CompanyId) + 1;
}
```

**Solicitation:**

I need a suggestions to stop repeatition on Next method in every class.

Thank you

Comment: `I am following IUnitOfWork Pattern` <= Why? The type `DbContext` is an implementation of a UoW pattern and the type `DbSet<T>` is an implementation of a Repository pattern. Why re-wrap these types in your own implementation of the same pattern? You are adding nothing of value, just more code and a poor abstraction which results in code that is harder to read, debug, and use.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with your custom `IUnitOfWork`, but I'm also unclear what is the scenario where you need to even call `Next`?  SQL Server can auto increment and will return the new id if you have configured everything correctly.

Comment: Why are you creating the next Id for a table?  Why not let your underlying db determine that for you?  Do you need to predict the next Id?  How can you be sure that 2 users aren't going to create the exact same number?

Comment: All right SqlServer auto-increment, but I need to send to user the next id on form page, because of that is necessary to know the next number Id.

Comment: Why do you need to send the user the next number?

Comment: With auto increment, EF will flow the id back for you already.  You don't need to do anything special.

Comment: See It http://prntscr.com/iad65y I brought to front-end Next-Number

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to implement Unit of Work pattern if you are using Entity Framework. If you click **F12/Go To Definition** on **DbContext** you'll see the following summary

> A DbContext instance represents a combination of the Unit Of Work and
>   Repository patterns such that it can be used to query from a database
>   and group together changes that will then be written back to the store
>   as a unit. DbContext is conceptually similar to ObjectContext.